# CSS prevent div push other div out of window

Tags: html, css

I am having difficulties keeping div's inside window. When the first div's hover effect works it pushes other divs to the right but last div goes out of window.

I've tried couple of things such as set the wrapper divs width fixed, changing position to fixed etc. but none of them works.

Ultimately I am trying to do the same of :https://artsandculture.withgoogle.com/en-us/national-parks-service/parks

Thank you for your time and help.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.grow {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.grow>div {
  flex-basis: 16.3%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  transition: .5s;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.grow>div:hover {
  flex-basis: 40%;
}

.grow>div:first-child:hover {
  margin-left: 25%;
}

.grow>div:last-child:hover {
  margin-right: 25%;
}

.box1{background-color:#2A75A}
.box2{background-color:#2A75A}
.box3{background-color:#2A75A}
.box4{background-color:#2A75A}
.box5{background-color:#2A75A}
.box6{background-color:#2A75A}
```

```html
<div class="grow">
      <div class='box1'>
        <div class="ninetyDegreeText">Box1</div>
        <div class="centeredText">Box1Html</div>
      </div>
      <div class='box2'>
        <div class="ninetyDegreeText" >Box2</div>
        <div class="centeredText">Box2</div>
      </div>
      <div class='box3'>
        <div class="ninetyDegreeText">Box3</div>
        <div class="centeredText">Box3Html</div>
      </div>
    <div class='box4'>
        <div class="ninetyDegreeText">Box4</div>
        <div class="centeredText">Box4Html</div>
      </div>
          <div class='box5'>
        <div class="ninetyDegreeText">Box5</div>
        <div class="centeredText">Box5Html</div>
      </div>
          <div class='box6'>
        <div class="ninetyDegreeText">Box6</div>
        <div class="centeredText">Box6Html</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The example you provided also pushes the elements outside of the horizontal viewport, so they keep their width, although on both sides. Do you want that, or do you want to shrink your other elements?

Comment: Yes. Indeed it pushes elements outside of the window but in my problem last div is completely goes out of screen.  It should at least can be seen so user can go over it. Thank you. @SteffenAndreasKloster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this solution helping you?

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.grow {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  max-width:100%;
  width:100%;
}

.grow>div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: 16.3%;
transition: all .3s ease-in;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.grow>div:hover {
  flex-basis: 40%;
}



.box1{background-color:#2A75A}
.box2{background-color:#2A75A}
.box3{background-color:#2A75A}
.box4{background-color:#2A75A}
.box5{background-color:#2A75A}
.box6{background-color:#2A75A}
```

```html
<div class="grow">
      <div class='box1'>
        <div class="ninetyDegreeText">Box1</div>
        <div class="centeredText">Box1Html</div>
      </div>
      <div class='box2'>
        <div class="ninetyDegreeText" >Box2</div>
        <div class="centeredText">Box2</div>
      </div>
      <div class='box3'>
        <div class="ninetyDegreeText">Box3</div>
        <div class="centeredText">Box3Html</div>
      </div>
    <div class='box4'>
        <div class="ninetyDegreeText">Box4</div>
        <div class="centeredText">Box4Html</div>
      </div>
          <div class='box5'>
        <div class="ninetyDegreeText">Box5</div>
        <div class="centeredText">Box5Html</div>
      </div>
          <div class='box6'>
        <div class="ninetyDegreeText">Box6</div>
        <div class="centeredText">Box6Html</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I actually tried max width and with but not together.. Can you tell me why both required to do this? Also I guess changes at the transition does anything? 

I mean I've tried lots of things. yet solution was that simple... thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Could something like this work? It doesn't work like the example provided, but it keeps all elements inside the viewport.

It changes the flex-basis to 0, to ensure they all have an equal width. When an element gets hovered, it changed that elements view-basis, and the others shrink because of `flex-basis: 0;`, to keep them equal.

This code was causing a lot of unwanted issues, so I removed it:

```
.grow>div:first-child:hover {
  margin-left: 25%;
}

.grow>div:last-child:hover {
  margin-right: 25%;
}
```

And none of your background-colors worked because of an invalid HEX value.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.grow {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.grow>div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  transition: flex-basis 500ms ease-in-out;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.grow>div:hover {
  flex-basis: 40%;
}

.box1{background-color:#1A75AA}
.box2{background-color:#2B75AA}
.box3{background-color:#3C75AA}
.box4{background-color:#4D75AA}
.box5{background-color:#5E75AA}
.box6{background-color:#6F75AA}
```

```html
<div class="grow">
      <div class='box1'>
        <div class="ninetyDegreeText">Box1</div>
        <div class="centeredText">Box1Html</div>
      </div>
      <div class='box2'>
        <div class="ninetyDegreeText" >Box2</div>
        <div class="centeredText">Box2</div>
      </div>
      <div class='box3'>
        <div class="ninetyDegreeText">Box3</div>
        <div class="centeredText">Box3Html</div>
      </div>
    <div class='box4'>
        <div class="ninetyDegreeText">Box4</div>
        <div class="centeredText">Box4Html</div>
      </div>
          <div class='box5'>
        <div class="ninetyDegreeText">Box5</div>
        <div class="centeredText">Box5Html</div>
      </div>
          <div class='box6'>
        <div class="ninetyDegreeText">Box6</div>
        <div class="centeredText">Box6Html</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```